# how to Read page respond of the payment result MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, payment, streamreader, httpwebresponse

basically my application is similar to the link but mine is on MVC C#.

-Make a payment request. -Read the Respond. -Pass the respond to our api.

https://developer.2c2p.com/docs/prepare-payment-request

my payment request code:

```
function CreateForm(parameters)
{
    var form = $('<form id="PaymentForm1"></form>');
    var path = url;  

    form.attr("method", "post");
    form.attr("action", path);

    $.each(parameters, function (key, value) {
        var field = $('<input></input>');
        field.attr("type", "hidden");
        field.attr("name", key);
        field.attr("value", value);
        console.log(key, value);
        form.append(field);
    });
    $(document.body).append(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

So my problem now is the response result on how to read it... and pass it in our api.
(similar to this but on MVC https://developer.2c2p.com/docs/read-payment-response)

I try to use this code..  `WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(resultURL);` but will reload the page, data will be gone.

```
[HttpGet]

        public ActionResult getResultValues()
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(resultURL);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            return View(responseFromServer);

        }
```

Is there a better way to do it? I'm also new on MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chenz101

Looking my code

Make a class for below formats

```
using System;   
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Linq;   
using System.Web;   
  
namespace AspNetMvcJqueryAjaxSerializeForm.Models   
{   
    public class FriendModel   
    {   
        public string FriendName { get; set; }   
        public string Phone { get; set; }   
        public string State { get; set; }   
    }   
}
```

Controller

```
// POST: Friend/AddFriend  
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult AddFriend(FriendModel fm)  
{  
          //Write your database insert code / activities  
            return RedirectToAction("create");  
}
```

This is the your MVC view html page code

```
<form id="friendform">   
    <table>   
        <tr>   
            <td>Friend Name</td>   
            <td><input id="txtFriendName" name="FriendName" type="text" /></td>   
        </tr>   
        <tr>   
            <td>Phone</td>   
            <td><input id="txtPhone" name="Phone" type="text" /></td>   
        </tr>   
        <tr>   
            <td>State</td>   
            <td><input id="txtState" name="State" type="text" /></td>   
        </tr>  
    </table>   
 <input id="btnsubmit" type="button" value="Submit"/>   
</form>
```

This is the your ajax call code

```
<script>   
    $(document).ready(function () {   
        $("#btnsubmit").click(function (e) {   
            //Serialize the form datas.   
            var valdata = $("#friendform").serialize();   
            //to get alert popup   
            alert(valdata);   
            $.ajax({   
                url: "/Friend/AddFriend",   
                type: "POST",   
                dataType: 'json',   
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',   
                data: valdata   
            });   
        });   
    });   
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Purvesh, yes i do same thing earlier this morning.. to solve that problem.I was trying to avoid creating model since it return a lot of data. But yes it works like this.